# Does python have pipeline tools or modules like DirectShow in Windows?

Tags: python, linux, pipeline

I want to make a pipeline to execute many process. I know there's a tool called DirectShow in Windows.

I have so many stages to execute and each stage is a process, so I need a pipeline tool to manage it.

Is there any library or tools in python?

Comment: Are you referring to microsoft's media-streaming architecture directshow?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony yes, but I want some tool like directshow in python.

Comment: Then I assume, that you want to look into something like `gstreamer`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony BTW, if I just want a pipeline or topology library in python?
I found gstreamer has pipeline, but I found almost audio-relation function in gstreamer.